# calling ajax call according to user permissions

Tags: asp.net, jquery

I have jquery buttons in my website,but some of these buttons doesnt have to clickable by every user so there must be permissions, all buttons make ajax calls so how can i control that buttons, for example if I have 3 buttons like:

```
button1_click()
some ajaxcalls

button2_click()
some other ajax calls

button3_click()
another calls
```

so admin can call this events, but simple user only have to call button3's 
what kind of approach I need? 
-Do i have to control every button using another ajax call like:

```
button1_click()
    an ajax call (permission.aspx) read session,admin or not,return true or false
    if(true)    
    {
      someajaxcall()
    }
```

-Or I have to hide or show buttons according to session? but i dont know how can i do that. 
**I m using jqgrid asp.net  components so that grid has custombuttons but that buttons doesnt have id so i cant reach it from serverside and also that buttons doesnt have visible or disable properties.**

 Im using asp.net and jquery

Comment: Why not User.IsInRole on server side? Ajax call won't be even in the HTML page (moreover you have to double check inside method).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normally I prefer to not show buttons that people can't use, so since you are using asp.net on the back end, you can hide the button when the page is created after checking the user's permissions, i.e:

```
  btnOne.Visible = UserIsAdministrator; //you need to define thisvariable based on your own rules.
```

etc

If you want to show them anyway, you could do btnOne.Enabled = UserIsAdministrator instead, which will show the buttons, but disable them as appropriate;

Comment: thanks for answer,I m using jqgrid asp.net  components so that grid has custombuttons but that buttons doesnt have id so i cant reach it from serverside and also that buttons doesnt have visible or disable properties.

Answer (score 1):

you can use a `hiddenfield` on that page which will hold the user roles. then inside the `DOM Ready()` function iterate through those buttons to make them enabled/disabled.
However, you should also check the roles in the server side after an ajax call is made in case someone manually changes the value of the hiddenfield to enable the buttons.